# Facebook chat only page

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-messenger

I don't remember exactly how I got to it, but I opened a page (external possibly) that only showed the chat interface of Facebook. It was quite similar to the [gabtastik screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmMEI.png)

[image]

What I wanted was to create a Chrome Application shortcut for this page, and easily use Facebook chat as a side along application. However, I've not been able to find such a page. Is it possible to open the Facebook chat only interface directly (without using any third party scripts)?

---

Previously, once logged into Facebook, you could use the URL http://www.facebook.com/presence/popout.php — this no longer works (as of 12th October 2011) — or from any Facebook page chat (in the bottom left) → *Options* → *Pop out*.

The second option no longer works with the new Chat UI—18th July 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has announced the launch of a web-only no-frill version of their messenger:

### [messenger.com](https://www.messenger.com/)

It is now available worldwide.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative method, is to use the [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) chat client instead.

The settings you need are:

- **Protocol:** XMPP
- **Username:** [your current Facebook username] (see step 1)
- **Domain:** chat.facebook.com

  1. Currently, you’ll need a Facebook Username (ie, facebook.com/mikeknoop).
  2. Open up Pidgin, Click Accounts, then Manage Accounts. Now click Add.
  3. Fill in the Basic tab with the following details:
- **Resource:** [unused, you may leave blank]
- **Password:** [your current Facebook password]

  1. On the Advanced tab, make sure all SSL options are unchecked.
  2. Click Add. You’re done!

Answer (score 6):

I mostly use the mobile website http://m.facebook.com/messages

Besides the chat functionality of course, it gives me:

- Cross platform access without being dependent on installation rights.
- No Facebook icon in my taskbar (annoying if you're working at consultancy).
- No Windows notifications when you have a new message.
- Quick access to my timeline notifications.

**Update 09-04-2015**: As of 09/04/2015 Messenger is available on the web https://messenger.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use Facebook's very own messenger webapp:

https://www.messenger.com/

---

As @Peter stated, you can already use a [Multi-IM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotocol_instant_messaging_application) client. Just wanted to point out that there are many already around:

- [Trillian](http://trillian.im/)
- [Adium](http://adium.im/) (Mac only)
- [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/)

E.g.: in Trillian there's already a Facebook plugin integrated, so you just need to provide your username (and you'll see the usual Facebook connect pop-up where you have to login and grant access).

You can check the very long list of (Facebook-chat-capable) multi-IMs here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients#Multiprotocol_clients

Answer (score 0):

One option I like is to just go to https://www.facebook.com/mobile?_rdr . It doesn't redirect to mobile but the background is static promoting Facebook mobile apps and you get full chat on the bottom bar