# How to pop out the new Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, chat, user-interface, facebook-messenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook chat only page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/facebook-chat-only-page)

Facebook has rolled out a new chat UI. I always used to use the option 'pop out chat' that appeared in the menu at the top of the chat interface, however that option is not there now.

Is it still possible to do? If so, how do I find that option?

[image]

Comment: Why was this closed? The 'exact duplicate' question was for BEFORE the UI had changed. See the part 'or from any facebook page chat (in the bottom left) -> options -> pop out' on the link - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/facebook-chat-only-page

Hence why I said I will accept this as the answer if there is no way through the UI... and why the question is the NEW Facebook chat.

The downvote was uncalled for.